# How to extract substrings from filenames using batch files?

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently using batch files to process file names that have a timestamp (`AFL-YYYYMMDHHMMSS-BKS-0.910-11`.). Example:

```
AFL-20130131144045-BKS-0.910-11
```

I want to extract a substring from these file names in order to keep the `BKS`" and `.910-11` (.910-11 is a file extention).

How can I achieve this with a batch file?

Comment: can you provide more information? I am not able to understand your question

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
@echo off
for %%x in (AFL-*-BKS-*.*-*) do (
for /f "delims=-. tokens=3,5-6" %%a in ("%%x") do (
echo %%a .%%b-%%c
)
)
pause >nul
```

Here I have just printed the result to the screen, it's up to you what you want to do with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

just rename it after copy to BKS 910-11

Answer (score 0):

paste the code into note pad and save it in bat file and try running

copy C:\mydir*BKS*910-11* D:\newdir